# Cannot find the server process which execute through puppet exec command

Tags: wso2, puppet

I start-up a server in a agent machine through puppet master.Here is my `exec` command which i use for it ( Note : this is called using collector )

```
Change_config::Fill_template<| |> -> Exec<| title == "strating" |>

exec { "strating":
user        => 'root',
environment => "JAVA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/tools/jdk1.6.0_45",
path        => $command_path,
command     => "sh ${agentLocation}/${product_pack}/bin/wso2server.sh ${serverOptions}",
logoutput => true,
timeout => 3600,
}
```

Then I log in to agent machine and open the server log which I started-up. Server log says the server up and running

```
[2014-08-22 13:05:47,717]  INFO    {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener} -  HTTPS port       : 9443
[2014-08-22 13:05:47,718]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener} -  HTTP port        : 9763
[2014-08-22 13:05:49,468]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
[2014-08-22 13:05:49,469]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Message Broker-2.2.0
[2014-08-22 13:05:49,469]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 23 sec
[2014-08-22 13:05:49,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://10.0.2.82:9443/carbon/
```

But when I check the ports using `netstat -ntlp` it don't shows me the ports. (both normal and root users ). There is no sign of the server except the log. 
Finally , I start-up the server again manually inside my agent and then I could observed the ports ( Normally this should give a exception because i am trying to use existing ports if puppet has started-up the server successfully. but it didn't give any exception)

This is weird situation. I cannot understand why i cannot see the server evidence which start-up through puppet. Could you provide me a clue for this behavior?

Note: When I run 'puppet agent --test' manually inside the agent node, it start-up the server and I can see the port bindings. I suspect the problem is when the agent get the catalog in the start-up daemon.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, the agent is killing the server when the `Exec`'s timeout expires.  It perhaps does so forcefully enough that the server does not log a shutdown.  You can afterward start the server again manually because at that point it is no longer running.

You should instead manage the service via a `Service` resource.  To that end it would be best to create a proper service control script for your environment, but the `Service` resource type is flexible enough to handle the job for *ad hoc* services such as yours currently is.  Something like this might do it:

```
service { 'wso2service':
  ensure     => 'running',
  hasstatus  => false,
  hasrestart => false,
  start      => "/bin/sh ${agentLocation}/${product_pack}/bin/wso2server.sh ${serverOptions}",
  stop       => "/usr/bin/killall wso2server.sh",
  pattern    => 'wso2server\.sh'
}
```

But really, create a proper initscript, or whatever initscript analog your system uses.  Then you can simplify that to just

```
service { 'wso2service':
  ensure     => 'running',
}
```